# How do I order multidimensional array by average order of sub-arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Sorry for the confusing sounding title

I have some rows from a database that I have performed `array_flip()` on, and I have also ordered each sub-array by values using some complicated sorting patterns

I now have data in the form:

```php
array(
   'col1' => array(0=>'value',1=>'value',2=>'value',3=>'value'),
   'col2' => array(1=>'value',2=>'value',0=>'value',3=>'value'),
   'col3' => array(0=>'value',2=>'value',1=>'value',3=>'value')
);
```

Note that the 0,1,2,3 are not in order for each sub-array

What I want is to come up with an order that is the average across all columns, in the case of these 3 it would be: 0, 2, 1, 3

I then want to apply this order to all columns, so they are all in the order 0, 2, 1, 3

I can then flip the columns back again, and re-insert into a new table, then happy days all my items are in order

**It is probably an easy problem, but I am just not seeing the solution, could anybody please point me in the right direction?**

Note: Column count and column names varies

Comment: By average you mean _0 + 1 + 0 = 1 / 3 = 0_ and likewise?

Comment: Can you make an example of what you got and what you want?

Comment: Did you mean something like this? https://3v4l.org/W4okj

Comment: @nice_dev I think this is what I was looking for, that is amazing thanks - I've just done a few tests and it seems to be generally right although struggles with certain scenarios, I am sure I can adapt it from there, thanks so much - please make answer so I can accept it - think I have had blinkers on, I wanted the average, but I didn't think to actually average like ( 0 + 1 + 0 ) / 3 lol

Comment: @user16861522 I can surely put an answer but could you elaborate on tests where it _struggles_  ? I am also rounding the average value, not sure if it aligns with your requirement?

Comment: My only concern is rounding up vs down, if two values average to 0.5, they will both round up causing a duplicate for example

Comment: @user16861522 Fair enough. You will have to find some other way to re-order things then if it's so necessary in the first place.

Comment: @nice_dev It is really just a visual thing - if I have a product like "drop leaf table" each individual size has different dimensions etc, and I want to display them on the website in order smallest to largest, but some of the values are a little more complex to calculate than just a regular asort for certain products (or inches for example) - I could sort them on the page, but if I am going to sort them anyway that is the hard part - might as well presort the database then not bother to sort them further

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example implementation:

```
$data = [
    'col1' => [0 => 'value', 1 => 'value', 2 => 'value', 3 => 'value'],
    'col2' => [1 => 'value', 2 => 'value', 0 => 'value', 3 => 'value'],
    'col3' => [0 => 'value', 2 => 'value', 1 => 'value', 3 => 'value'],
];


$averages = [];
foreach ($data as $column => $subArray) {
    asort($subArray); 
    $average = array_sum(array_keys($subArray)) / count($subArray); 
    $averages[$column] = $average;
}


uasort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($averages) {
    return $averages[$a] <=> $averages[$b];
});




$data = array_flip($data);
```

This code will output:

```
Array
(
    [col1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
            [2] => value
            [1] => value
            [3] => value
        )

    [col2] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
            [2] => value
            [1] => value
            [3] => value
        )

    [col3] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
            [2] => value
            [1] => value
            [3] => value
        )
)
```

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT